# How to set a column field on a Journal entry to false

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to set a mandatory column field(through UI at field level) to false on a Journal Entry record.

I need to use User Event script because the journal entries are system generated and the same custom field should be mandatory for other transactions.

I have tried using a user event before load and setMandatory(false) but it is not working.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function removeMandatory(type)
{
  if(type == 'create')
  {
     for( var i =1 ; i < nlapiGetLineItemCount('line') ; i++)
         {
           var customField =  nlapiGetLineItemField('line', 'custcol_test_mandatory', i);
           customField.setMandatory(false);
         }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Rusty Shackles:

I have actually worked it out using User Event Before Load function. Here is the code:

```
function notMandatoryBeforeLoad(type)
{
    var context = nlapiGetContext();
    if(type == 'create' && context.getExecutionContext() == 'scheduled')
    {
        var LineMandatoryField = nlapiGetLineItemField('line','custcol_test_mandatory');
    if (LineMandatoryField)
        {
        LineMandatoryField.setMandatory(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe field objects are read only if not done in a Suitelet.

What you can do is use a client side script that executes on field change/validate field and check if the "mandatory" field as a value.

Comment: I tired using the same script on client side LineInIt, but It is still not working

Comment: Line Init executes when you select the line.  Have you tried moving it to validate line